# Which Database to choose?

Tags: sql, database, selection, nosql

I have the following criteria

- Database should be protected with a username and password. It should not be possible to copy the database file and use it else were like MS Access.
- There will be no central database server. Each machine will run their own database server locally and user will initiate synchronization. Concept is inspired from distributed version control system like Git. So it should have good replication support.
- Strong consistency is not needed. Users will synchronize each other database when they need. In case of conflicts it should be possible to find the conflict and present it (from application) to the user for fixing it.
- Revisions of data if available it will be good. e.g. Entire history of change to a invoice.
- I explored document oriented database and inclined towards the same. But I dont know what to choose.
- Database is small it will not reach even 1GB in the next few years (say 3 years).

Please feel free to suggest any database which you think might be suitable. Any pointers is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bullet point 1 seems impossible to fulfill if you aren't using a centralized database. Where do you think a local database is going to keep data? It has to go in files somewhere.

Comment: @Mike Daniels: Could be encrypted files.

Comment: @Thilo: OK, makes sense. I guess I was treating the two parts of bullet 1 as two separate requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the one which I am looking for:

> From [official site](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html): CouchDB is a peer-based distributed
>   database system, it allows for users
>   and servers to access and update the
>   same shared data while disconnected
>   and then bi-directionally replicate
>   those changes later.
>
> The CouchDB document storage, view and
>   security models are designed to work
>   together to make true bi-directional
>   replication efficient and reliable.
>   Both documents and designs can
>   replicate, allowing full database
>   applications (including application
>   design, logic and data) to be
>   replicated to laptops for offline use,
>   or replicated to servers in remote
>   offices where slow or unreliable
>   connections make sharing data
>   difficult.

Any idea how the couchDB data can be protected using user accounts? e.g. Mysql needs user to login to use the data. I am looking only for a simple authentication, not for something fool proof. I just do not want the data to be open for editing. Encrypting the file system seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Also, are there any tutorials about how to set up the bi-directional replication, and how conflicts are resolved there?

Comment: I was reading about replication. If we need bidirectional replication, it looks like we have to initiate replication on both sides. Following links might help:

http://books.couchdb.org/relax/reference/replication
http://books.couchdb.org/relax/reference/conflict-management

Comment: Additional links:
* http://japhr.blogspot.com/2010/03/extreme-couchdb-replication.html

* http://blog.couch.io/post/468392274/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-three-new

Comment: If you are going with CouchDB, maybe take a look at Desktopcouch: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the exact same thing. Have not found it yet. An interesting project in this space is Bestpractical's [Prophet](http://syncwith.us/) (and the bug tracker SD that is built on this). I have no idea how active it is, though, and I do not think it uses an encrypted file format (but in your scenario, whole-disk encryption would be a feasible solution).

Prophet's buzzword-laden pitch reads something like this:

> A grounded, semirelational, peer to peer replicated, disconnected, versioned, property database with self-healing conflict resolution.

Comment: +1 ... for finding a sentence with more buzzwords than all of Microsoft the SharePoint documentation combined.

Comment: @pst: Re: buzzwords: To be clear, the Prophet people are tongue-in-cheek about this themselves. "Prophet's buzzword-laden pitch" is a verbatim quote from the site.

Comment: Thank you for pointinh Prophet. Did you check CouchDB or MongoDB? Did you find any of them suitable. Last release of Prophet was in Aug-2009 which makes me think it might not be actively developed in future, so reluctant to choose the same. Any how I will give a try.

Comment: @Sundar: I looked at CouchDB when it was pretty new. At that time, it was unclear (at least to me) how to operate it in a peer-to-peer scenario. But yes, CouchDB is definitely something to check out.

Comment: CouchDB seems to be promising. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576838/which-database-to-choose/2577012#2577012

Answer (score 0):

I have done this where a vertical-market customer wanted to use my ClipMate program to store and distribute medical-related data, and didn't want the data to escape "into the wild".
I leveraged the encryption capability of the database (DBISAM by Elevatesoft, which has an engine that compiles directly into Delphi programs) and the "hardware locking" capability of my protection wrapper, Armadillo.
So when someone purchases the program from the vertical market customer, they get the app (download or CD) and install it. Upon installation, they are presented with a registration dialog that shows their "hardware fingerprint" (as reported by Armadillo). This is derived from their ethernet address, CPU serial, hard drive serial, etc., and I could be wrong on any of those, but that's the general idea. They call it in, and a key is generated that's unique to that end-user/machine combo.  The registration key "unlocks" the database, which is encrypted, and the encryption key is part of the registration code. 
The end-user cannot make any use of the data without the key, and they cannot give away or transfer the data without receiving another unlock code.  It's pretty tight.  Would be too annoying for a low-priced app, but they're charging a lot for it, so it's worth it.

Anyway, to recap:  The database is encrypted, and the encryption code is only accessible (to the program that reads the database) when the program is properly registered to a specific user/computer.

You COULD do this with Access, MySQL, etc.. Just encrypt the data, either at the database level (I suppose they support this, no?) or at the field level, if you want ultimate control and are ok with using a custom front-end app to read the thing.

Comment: What's stopping a user from taking the encryption key from one machine to another?

Comment: @Dietrich - he said the key is matched to the hardware fingerprint

Comment: Also, the point may be to prevent other people from getting to the data, not necessarily the legitimate user (who knows the key).

Comment: @Joel - Yes, but you can get the key from one computer, and copy it to another.  The key is just another piece of data.

Comment: @Dietrich, you can copy it over, but if the key is tied to the HW fingerprint, it isn't going to validate, and thus won't decrypt the database.

Comment: How exactly do you tie a key to a HW fingerprint?  That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Dietrich, suppose you buy some software and provide the following to the software vendor:
Name: Dietrich, HardwareFingerprint: 1234ABCD  
The vendor makes a string like this:
s := 'DIETRICHDIETRICHDI' + '1234ABCD' + '20100407' + 'SECRETDATABASEKEY';
Key := EncryptThis(S);  
Then he sends you this:
Licensed To: Dietrich
Key:  D827292B5D696080A62FF9E7334BA64FE820303FE06B3789BB9054C23BA875AD47F43BADB21E85441E3660F801B78EE4B46DE4

Now when the program runs, it uses an internal decryption key (in this case: 'SECRET') to extract those 4 pieces of info. (cont..)

Comment: (cont)
  Now it knows your name: 'DIETRICH', and can validate that against the name that you enter.  Ok, so it knows it's you.  It knows the hardware figerprint that the software was licensed to. 1234ABCD, and compares that against the actual hardware key. Ok, good.  The date can be checked, whatever. If everything looks good up to this point, it can pull the database encryption code (in this case 'SECRETDATABASEKEY'), and use that to decrypt the data.  There you go.

Comment: go to:  
http://www.fyneworks.com/encryption/RC4-Encryption/  
Key: SECRET 
Encrypted Data: D8 27 29 2B 5D 69 60 80 A6 2F F9 E7 33 4B A6 4F E8 20 30 3F E0 6B 37 89 BB 90 54 C2 3B A8 75 AD 47 F4 3B AD B2 1E 85 44 1E 36 60 F8 01 B7 8E E4 B4 6D E4 Try it!